# Methods not pulling through - Read Running Loop on Java Method, didn't fix my code

Tags: java, loops, methods

So I am a student. I am taking my first class in Java. I am sure my code is horrible, but please don't beat me up, I am really trying to learn. I have read quite a few method questions and adjusted my code according the the suggestions on this website. The closest post to my problem is Running Loop on Java Method. I adjusted my code according to the suggestions in this post, along with a few others. That said, it did not fix my problem. My methods are not pulling through properly.

Can anyone help? It will not pull any of the Boolean code into the main and I am not sure if the Boolean is pulling my methods correctly. Intro runs properly. Below is my code (edited down to include main and bool code only):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       intro(); // This works
       while (repeat()) //This does not work
           ;


    }//end Main

//None of this is being called
public static boolean repeat()
{
    //Assign Variables
    char calculate, calculateCS, repeat;
    double inchCircle, inchSphere, radiusCS, volume, volumeSphere, area, areaCircle;
    String shape;

    //Initialze Variables
    calculate = 1;
    area = 1;
    volume = 1;
    inchCircle = 1;
    inchSphere = 1;
    shape = "";        

    //Ask if user wants to repeat
    System.out.print("Do you want to calculate anouther round object (Y/N): ");
        if (!takeInput().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            System.out.println("Thank you for using the Round Object Calculator. Goodbye. ");
            return false;
        }

        else
        {
            printCircleSphere(shape);
            if (!printCircleSphere(shape).equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
                {
                    printRadiusC(inchCircle);
                    printCircle(area);
                }
            else if (!printCircleSphere(shape).equalsIgnoreCase("s"))
                printRadiusS(inchSphere);
                printSphere(volume);
        }
    return true;

}//end repeat
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your whole introduction isn't necessary. The only relevant part in it is "My methods are not pulling through properly". But this is a much too vague description of the problem. Remove all that introduction, and instead explain what you're trying to achieve, what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. Precisely.

Comment: @JB Nizet - I am sorry for supplying too much code. I am just not sure where I went wrong. I have edited it down. I pretty sure my issue is either with how I called my bool method or with how I wrote the bool method. I want it to loop based on two choices input by user, either calculate the area of a circle or the volume of a sphere. I am pretty sure I wrote all my methods correctly with the exception of the bool and the main. Not sure I am calling my other methods correctly.

Comment: Does it throw any error? If not, does it print the print statements? Is the problem occurring at system inputs?

Comment: If you add a `System.out.println();` after `intro();`, is it executed?

Comment: @PriyankGupta - It does not print the print statement. I know somehow I am not calling the Bool correctly. I can't even get ti to call just a sample portion of my code such as this:  public static void main(String[] args){
        
        String chooseSC = "  ";
        
        String chooseCircleSphere =  printCircleSphere(chooseSC);
        
        //Prompt the user for C for circle or S for sphere.
        System.out.print("Enter C for circle or S for sphere: "); 
        System.out.println(chooseCircleSphere);
        
    }

Comment: @NoRelect - if I add boolean repeat; as a variable and then type System.out.println(while (repeat = true)); I get an error of illegal start of expression.

Comment: @NoRelect - I figured out how to type in your suggestion and it worked: intro();
       
       System.out.println();
       while (repeat ())
       {
       }

Comment: Ok good. I was just checking if your code even gets to the while loop or if intro(); blocks

Comment: Could you try changing the call to `System.out.print()` in the `repeat()` method to `System.out.println()`? The `print()` version will only actually print something when its buffer is full and in your case it probably isn't, while the next line blocks waiting for user input even though no prompt has actually been printed.

Comment: @sisyphus - so I had to change this to a do - while loop and I can't even get to the repeat() line. I have some how created an infinite loop.

Comment: Anyone have an idea why this would not work?

String calculateCS, calculate;

calculate = " ";

calculateCS = printCircleSphere(calculate);


 public static String printCircleSphere(String chooseSC)
    {    
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Allows user to input the variable.
        return chooseSC = input.nextLine();

Comment: If you've changed the code causing the problem you should update the question directly.

Comment: A do...while loop does not alter the possibility that an unprinted prompt is making an input step wait without a prompt.

Comment: @sisyphus - you are correct. It was not the do while that is messing my code it is one of my methods where I am asking for user input and need to output the answer and make calculations based off their input. Thanks for everyone's help with the loop. Apparently my issue is calling a method.